# Python - Would Websocket Messages Received During 'on_message' Processing be Skipped?

Tags: python, websocket

I am using the python websocket-client module.

What I am trying to do is to listen to a websocket and process incoming messaged to be entered into my database.

My question is would incoming messages during the processing on the most recent message would cause any following messages to be missed?

If so, how do I go about solving this?

Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing the details of your implementation: likely *no*. The network stack and/or Python's internal implementation would *buffer* incoming messages until they're read by your code. Only if that buffer overflows might you lose messages.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid it and ensure it will be not affecting new messages, you can handle the message in a new thread like

```
t = threading.Thread(target=functiontohandlemessage(someargs, message)) 
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```